# Second order ODE with non-integral exponent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

Consider the following 2nd-order nonlinear ODE with non-integral exponent. It arises from a diffusion problem in electrochemistry with a concentration-dependent sink term:

$y''-cy^\alpha=0$

with $c>0$ and $0<\alpha<1$. I'm looking for the real-valued solution that should be non-negative, since $y$ represents a concentration. Of particular interest are the special cases $\alpha=1/4$ and $\alpha=1/2$.

Comment: this leads to a hypergeometric series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the closed form solution using [**Inverse Beta Regularized $\text I^{-1}_s(a,b)$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Inverse+Beta+Regularized) and [the Incomplete Beta function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Beta%28x%2Ca%2Cb%29) Leaving off from @JJacquelin’s solution using $\alpha=a$:

$$x=\pm \frac y{\sqrt{c_1}}\:_2\text{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\:,\: \frac{1}{a+1}\:;\: \frac1{a+1}+1\:;\:-\frac{2c\,y^{a+1}}{c_1(a
+1)}\right)+c_2= \pm \frac y{\sqrt{c_1}}\frac1{a+1}\left(-\frac{2c\,y^{a+1}}{c_1(a+1)}\right)^{-\frac1{a+1}}\text B_{-\frac{2c\,y^{a+1}}{c_1(a+1)}}\left(\frac1{a+1},\frac12\right)+c_2=  c_2\pm \sqrt[a+1]{\frac{c_1(a+1)}{2c}}\frac{\text B_{\frac{2c\,y^{a+1}}{c_1(a+1)}}\left(\frac1{a+1},\frac12\right)}{\sqrt{c_1}(a+1)}$$

Now invert:

$$y’’=cy^a\implies y=\sqrt[a+1]{-\frac{(a+1)c_1}{2c}\text I^{-1}_\frac{\sqrt[a+1]{-\frac{2c}{c_1 (a+1)}}\sqrt{c_1}(a+1)(x-c_2)
}{\text B\left(\frac1{a+1},\frac12\right)}\left(\frac1{a+1},\frac12\right)};0\le\frac{\sqrt[a+1]{-\frac{2c}{c_1 (a+1)}}\sqrt{c_1}(a+1)(x-c_2)
}{\text B\left(\frac1{a+1},\frac12\right)}\le1,a>0$$

[**which**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand+ddy+ddy+%28-%28%28%281+%2B+a%29+k+InverseBetaRegularized%5B%28-s+%2B+y%29%2F%28+1%2Fsqrt%28k%29+1%2F%28a%2B1%29%28-%282+c%29%2F%28k+%2B+a+k%29%29%5E%28-1%2F%28a%2B1%29%29*beta%281%2F%28a%2B1%29%2C1%2F2%29%29%2C+%281+%2B+a%29%5E%28-1%29%2C+1%2F2%5D%29%2F%282c%29%29%29%5E%281+%2B+a%29%5E%28-1%29) [**works**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-1%29%5E%281%2B3%2F%281%2Ba%29%292%5E%28-1%2B%281%2Ba%29%5E%28-1%29%29%281%2Ba%29%5E%281%2B%281%2Ba%29%5E%28-1%29%29c%5E%281%2Ba%29%5E%28-1%29k%5E%281%2B%281%2Ba%29%5E%28-1%29%29g*%28k%2Ba+k%29%5E%28-2%2F%281+%2B+a%29%29%3D2%5E%28-a%2F%281+%2B+a%29%29+c%5E%281%2F%281+%2B+a%29%29+%28-1%29%5E%28%28+4+%2B+a%29%2F%281+%2B+a%29%29+g+*%28%281+%2B+a%29+k%29%5E%28a%2F%281+%2B+a%29%29) when seeing the first link’s “Expanded form assuming” section and simplifying the coefficients with the second link

Special cases include specific cases of the [Jacobi Amplitude](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=jacobiamplitude) and [Weierstrass P](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=weierstrassp)

Answer (score 1):

$$y''-cy^\alpha=0$$
$$2y''y'-2cy^\alpha y'=0 \quad\to\quad y'^2-\frac{2c}{\alpha+1} y^{\alpha+1}=c_1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y'=\pm\sqrt{c_1+\frac{2c}{\alpha+1} y^{\alpha+1}}$$
$$x=\pm\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{c_1+\frac{2c}{\alpha+1} y^{\alpha+1}}}+c_2$$
$$x=\pm \frac{y}{\sqrt{c_1}}\:_2\text{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\:,\: \frac{1}{\alpha+1}\:;\: \frac{\alpha+2}{\alpha+1}\:;\:-\frac{2c\,y^{\alpha+1}}{c_1(\alpha+1)}\right)+c_2$$
where $_2$F$_1$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function.

This gives $x$ as a function of $y$. It is doubtful that a closed form exists for the inverse function $y(x)$ in the general case, that is for any $\alpha$ in the specified range.

Comment: Appreciated! Mathematica tells me that the fourth argument of the Gauss hypergeometric function is actually $-\frac{2cy^{\alpha+1}}{c_1(\alpha+1)}$, i.e., with $y^{\alpha+1}$ in the numerator rather than the denominator.

Comment: Right ! A typo in copying. Fixed.

Comment: @Roman There is also an explicit solution using [Inverse beta regularized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Inverse+Beta+Regularized), but the domain is small. Should this answer be added?

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Sure, go ahead if it adds something relevant and new!