# Reduction of Order to Solve $y'' =-y^{3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, reduction-of-order-ode

I want to solve $y'' +y^3 = 0$ with the boundary conditions $y(0) = a$ and $y(k) = b$. My goal is to reduce this problem to $y' +y^2 = 0$ while solving but I'm not sure it can be done.

I tried reduction of order substitutions (ie. taking $y' = w$ and $y'' = \frac{dw}{dy}y'$) but that did not work. Then I tried to solve in the following way

$y'' y' = -y^3 y'$

$\frac{1}{2}[(y')^2]' = -[\frac{1}{4} y^4]'$

$\frac{1}{2}(y')^2 = -\frac{1}{4} y^4+C$

$(y')^2 = -\frac{1}{2} y^4+C$

$y' = \pm \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2} y^4+C}$

It seems to me if I take my original problem to be $y'' - 2y^3 = 0$ instead, I get
$y' = \pm \sqrt{y^4+C}$. If $C=0$, this would reduce to $y' - y^2 = 0$, which is close enough to what I want for my purposes. But I'm not sure how to get $C=0$ without a condition on the derivative, so maybe this was the wrong way to go.

1. Can I reduce my original problem, $y'' +y^3 = 0$, to $y' +y^2 = 0$?
2. Where do my boundary conditions come into play?

Comment: $y'' = y^{-3}$ is *not* equivalent to $y'' + y^3 = 0$.

Comment: @Dan sorry that was a silly typo. Fixed it :)

Comment: Also, $y’+y^2=0$ has a [simple solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y’%2By%5E2%3D0), but the solution to [$y’’=cy^a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440360/second-order-ode-with-non-integral-exponent/4500264#4500264) is here and involves elliptic functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve
\begin{gather*}
\boxed{y^{\prime \prime}+y^{3}=0}
\end{gather*}
Multiplying the ode by $y^{\prime}$ gives
$$
y^{\prime} y^{\prime \prime}+y^{3} y^{\prime} = 0
$$
Integrating the above w.r.t $x$ gives
\begin{align*}
\int \left(y^{\prime} y^{\prime \prime}+y^{3} y^{\prime}\right)d x &= 0 \\ 
\frac{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}}{2}+\frac{y^{4}}{4} = c_2
\end{align*}
Which is now solved for $y$.
Solving for $y^{\prime}$ gives
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime}&=\frac{\sqrt{-2 y^{4}+8 c_{2}}}{2}\tag{1} \\ 
y^{\prime}&=-\frac{\sqrt{-2 y^{4}+8 c_{2}}}{2}\tag{2} 
\end{align*}

These are separable which can be solved by integration.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This matches exactly what I was getting. Is there instead a way to get the ODE $y' + y^2 = 0$ from the original problem?

Comment: @k12345 I am little confused. The ode $y''+y^3=0$ does not have the same solution as $y'+y^2=0$. So how could the first lead to the second then? If there was a way, then both should have same solution, right? Which tells me it is not possible convert the first to the second.

Comment: you are completely correct. My question was silly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$y'+y^2=0$$
Differentiate:
$$y''+2yy'=0$$
$$y''+2y(-y^2)=0$$
$$y''-2y^3=0$$
So you will never end with the second order DE you posted.
$$y'' +y^3 = 0$$